# Is the Selenium IDE test case property "Title" accessible to my script?

Tags: selenium, ide

For example, if I create a new test case in the IDE, and it appears in the left hand side window pane, then right click that test case and chose **"Properties"**, there are two properties available ... one of them is **"Title"**.

The IDE allows one to create separate titles for each test case, even if you have included the same test case twice.

For example, I might have a script where I want to login twice (just an example only to serve the purpose of this question).

I could provide a title for the first instance of the login.html test case as "1st login", then add some test case, logout, and login again ... then title the second instance of the login.html test case as "2nd Login".

This is very handy. However, I want to be able to access the title value in the test itself. In that way, I might know that I am on the first or second instance of the same test case file.

I know some of you may have other opinions about how to accomplish the goal, but keep in mind, I am only using this as an example ...

I want to find out if the **"Title"** is available to me **programmatically** during a test run.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but maybe this can help.

"**storeLocation**" command is useful to store current selected window's URL in selenium IDE. The web application's URL will be stored into variable "varTitle1" and you will be able to use that variable value anywhere in your script.

```
*Command - Target* 
open - https://www.google.com
storeLocation - varTitle
echo -  ${varTitle}
```

"**storeTitle**" command is storing title of current opened software web application's title. It will store current selected windows title in to variable "varTitle2".

```
Command - Target 
open - https://www.google.com
storeTitle - varTitle2
echo -  ${varTitle2}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the title I was referring to was not the title or location of the application under test (AUT), I am referring to the title property of the test case file itself. Follow my instructions in the question above and right click on the test case file in the left hand pane, and select "Properties" from the context menu. You then will see the "Title" value I am referring to.

Comment: This function does not appear in Selenium IDE. But why you want to have the case title in your test? Why not put a comment  on the first line with the title of your case?

There is one place that I would see is when you press the Source tab in Selenium IDE to see the XML version of the test, you can see the <title> </title>.

Comment: I am confused. This function DOES exist in the IDE. Please follow the instructions above and you will find the title property for the test case file. Adding a comment in the actual test case, does not allow you to reference the test case file in the context of its order/usage in the suite when you use the same test case file in the same suite multiple times.